# Xcode random compile errors Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: xcode, ios

Recently, my Xcode has been going crazy. I randomly get errors tagged while compiling an iOS app in Swift:

```
"Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"
```

Which prevents the build to succeed. I build again and it's gone. 
Sometimes, I have to go to the line of code they point to, add a random space somewhere and then it works.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is your compiler installation corrupt?

Comment: How can I find that out? It's possible. It was happening on Xcode 6.3 randomly. Just updated it to Xcode 7 and now it's all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me also, I've managed to fix this by modifying my code.
The swift code seemed OK, but was not (from the compiler point of view).
The last case this afternoon, was

```
func InstallApplicationEventHandler(handler:EventHandlerUPP,...){}

let ret = InstallApplicationEventHandler(NewEventHandlerUPP({(nextHandler, theEvent, userData) -> OSStatus in ...
```

removing the `NewEventHandlerUPP(` code made the code compile OK.
Sorry, I don't know why.